# Как отправить PUSH организации из GitKraken?

Tags: git, github

Доброго вермени суток!
Есть организация на гитхабе. В ней репозиторий. На компьютере клон этого репозитория, открытый в GitKraken. При попытке PUSH пишет:

> If Script is organisation, you may need to request or grant access to the organisation for GitKraken

Как решить? Заранее спасибо.